# Stars and placemarks disappear when zooming in on lat: 10, lng: 9

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I'm using the Google Earth Plugin with the sky map data and I've found a part of the sky that seems to have a glitch. The attached jsfiddle shows the placemark I create and nearby celestial objects as it's flying in, but past a certain point, they all disappear. If  you zoom out enough, it comes back, but I can't get zoom in enough.

If I change the star coordinates to something else (e.g. `{lat: -4.14463888888889, lng: -74.877625}`), it works just fine. Try it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/D9Ade/6/

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Google Earth plugin from 7.0.3.8542 to 7.1.1.1580 and it started working!